# The Critical Value of $f(x)= x^{6\over 5}-12x^{1 \over 5}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need to find the critical number of
$$f(x)= x^{6\over 5}-12x^{1 \over 5}$$
Here's what I've tried.

$$f'(x) = {6 \over 5}x^{1\over 5} - {12\over 5}x^{-{4 \over 5}}\\
= {6x^{1\over 5} \over 5} - {12 \over 5x^{4\over 5}}$$

Now what do I do? I am having trouble finding when $f'(x) = 0$ or undefined which is the critical number.

Comment: $0=\frac 65x^\frac15-\frac{12}5x^{-\frac45}$.  Can you think of a way to manipulate this to solve for $x$?  What happens if $x=0$?  What happens if $x\neq0$ and you multiply both sides by $x^\frac 45$?

Comment: No I am not sure @abiessu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint assume $x^{1/5}=z$ so it becomes $f'(x)=1.2z-2.4z^{-4}=0$ can you do it now. So we get $z^5-2=0$ so $x^{1/5}=2^{1/5}$ thus $x=2$

Comment: I got ${6 \over 5}z^{-4}(z^5 -2)$

Comment: I have edited see it

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  $x\neq 0$, so try multiplying through by $\frac 56x^\frac 45$ in

$$0=\frac 65x^\frac15-\frac{12}5x^{-\frac45}$$

> $0=x-2$